# If there are nonzero elements $a$ and $b$ in $A$ such that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$, then $A$ has characteristic 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Let $A$ be a finite integral domain. If there are nonzero elements $a$ and $b$ in $A$ such that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$, then $A$ has characteristic 2.

I was thinking, if $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = a^2 + b^2$, wouldn't that mean that $2ab = 0$? But I thought that would be a contradiction since $A$ is a finite integral domain and has no zero divisors. I am not sure where I am confused.

However, I do think I know how to prove the statement. We know that in any integral domain of characteristic $p$, then $(a+b)^p = a^p + b^p$. Thus 2 is either the characteristic or 2 divides the characteristic. Since the characteristic must be prime, then 2 is the characteristic for $A$.

Comment: $2$ is not a member of the integral domain, however. $2ab$ just means $ab+ab$. There is no reason $ab+ab$ can't be zero, it just tells you something about the ring...

Comment: Is A commutative?

Comment: @math635 My class has defined an integral domain to be a commutative ring with unity that has the cancellation property.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I prefer to think about it like so: $2$ is a member of every integral domain; its the element $1+1$. What we don't necessarily have is a guarantee that $2$ is a different element from $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an if and only if, prove both ways.

- If the characteristic is $2$, then $2 = 0$, so $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 = a^2 + b^2$
- If $a, b \ne 0$ are such that $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$, then $2 a b = (a + b)^2 - a^2 - b^2 = 0$. As $a b \ne 0$, and it is an integral domain, it has no zero divisors, so $2 = 0$.

Comment: Oh this is very interesting. I would have not thought of it that way.